# Cannot find type 'SKAdImpression' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, macos

I'm trying to implement MoPub into my Swift app, but in some of the files that are provided by the MoPub pod there are errors saying `Cannot find type 'SKAdImpression' in scope`. I also cannot `import MoPub` in my own documents. I tried running `pod update` restarting xcode, and making sure I am using the .xcworkspace file

Edit: I just re-read the apple documentation, and noticed that it says SKAdImpression is an iOS 14.5+ feature. The version of Xcode I have is for iOS 14.4, so it makes sense as to why it cannot be found. My only concern is, does this mean that my app will only work on iOS 14.5+?

Edit 2: My mac does not support the latest MacOS which is required for the latest Xcode for 14.5. Is there anything I can do to get MoPub working anyway?

Comment: On a side note, I believe it should be `import MoPubSDK` -- not `import MoPub`. Can you post your pod file so I can see how you're integrating the SDK?

Comment: ```# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'AnimeWheel' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'mopub-ios-sdk', '5.17.0'
end
```
Here is my podfile

Comment: No idea if this will help or not, but you could try `pod 'mopub-ios-sdk'` instead of `pod 'mopub-ios-sdk', '5.17.0'`. I'm using MoPub in my own app, and I have the former.

Comment: I just tried that now and I reran `pod update` but I still have the same issue. I also tried importing MoPubSDK instead but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The version of Xcode I have is for iOS 14.4
> My mac does not support the latest MacOS

Bad news is that is there is no other way around this error, as far as I can see.
What did **not** help:

- Removing the version, `pod 'mopub-ios-sdk'` and running `pod install` of `pod update` again.
- Cleaning Build Folder.
- Cleaning the /DerivedData folder.

What did help:

- Updating Xcode to the 12.5 version.

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be the solution. I had to use a patch to allow my Mac to install MacOS Big Sur, just to update Xcode to 12.5, which allowed me to use the MoPub SDK with no errors.

Comment: This answer didn't help me unfortunately, I did update XCODE to 12.5 and same error

Answer (score 0):

Take the version out.

pod 'mopub-ios-sdk'

run `pod install`

Alternatively you can follow this from their guide:

> simply import MoPubSDK/MoPub-Bridging-Header.h to your project and
> ensure that the Objective-C Bridging Header build setting under Swift
> Compiler - Code Generation has a path to the header.

They also have a sample program, take a look at that as well.  You can find it here:
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/tree/master/Canary

Also, make sure you have the project closed out before you run pod install.  I have seen issues in the past when this happens.

Comment: I removed the version from the pod and ran `pod update` and `pod install` both with Xcode closed and I still have the same issue